# Protocol Oriented Programming in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, oop, functional-programming

Can someone please elaborate what exactly is ***protocol oriented programming***, and how/why is it the best approach for programming when using Apple's Swift language.

Also, does this approach improve the code performance when compared against traditional OOP/Functional approaches ?

I already watched the [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=408) video, and would like to have the basics clarified before diving deep.

Thanks.